# Auto width or height in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

As we know in android we can use

```
android:width='wrap_content'
android:height='match_parent'
```

to set width or height of the views.
but, in xamarin forms we cannot use that.

so how can i set dynamic width or height for my xamarin forms component? 
like `match_parent` or `wrap_content` in android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Xamarin.Forms you do the same using the LayoutOptions.

Let's say you have a Button which you want to grow horizontally (width) as its parent grow, you use:

```
var button4 = new Button {Text = "Click Me!", HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center};
```

**LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand** means it will take all the posible space available in its parent view (with some exceptions).

in XAML that'd be:

```
<Button Text="Click Me!"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

Suggest you to see the [Getting Started](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/) of Xamarin Forms.

Comment: hi @apineda thank for the answer, i have used your solution and work in stacklayout but it is fail when i use relativelayout, means the Button want not to be centered

Comment: That is because as happens in Android (java) when working with RelativeLayout the methods for positioning are not the same. The guide for the RelativeLayout in Xamarin.Forms can be seen here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the options under HorizontalOptions and VerticalOptions.  Sounds like FillAndExpand is what you are after.